# Want DropDownlist value to get stored by ID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on asp.net using VB and SQL database
I have two tables `mst_Emp` & `mst_dept`

`mst_dept` got following columns `(dpt_ID(PK),dpt_name,dpt_descrip)`

`mst_Emp` got following columns `(Emp_ID,Emp_FirstName,Emp_LastName,Emp_Address,Emp_ContactNo,Dept_ID(Foreign key),Marital_Status,Gender)`

Now I have a Employee Detail Form in that I have `Department Name label`(DataBind from `mst_Dept`) and I have `DropDownList` for that to select. If some choose value from `DropDownList` I want it to get stored by `Dept_ID` in database. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY GOT IT THANKS :-)**

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Dim sqlconn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PRGM\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HRMS;Integrated Security=True"
        sqlconn.Open()
        cmd1 = New SqlCommand("select Dpt_ID,Dpt_Name from mst_Dept", sqlconn)
        'Dim qry As String = "select Dpt_ID,Dpt_Name from mst_Dept"
        'cmd1 As New SqlCommand(qry, sqlconn)
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
        sda.Fill(ds)
        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("Dpt_ID").ColumnName
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("Dpt_Name").ColumnName
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select Department --")

        sqlconn.Close()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your Department `Dropdownlist` like

```
Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Conn").ConnectionString)
    If sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sqlconn.Open()
    End If
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Dim qry As String = "Select dpt_ID,dpt_name from mst_Dept"

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(qry, sqlconn)
        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        sda.Fill(ds)
        D_ddlDepartment.DataSource = ds
        D_ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "dpt_ID"
        D_ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "dpt_name"
        D_ddlDepartment.DataBind()
        D_ddlDepartment.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select Department --")
 If sqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
    sqlconn.Close()
 End If
    End Using
End Using
```

and you can access the `Dept_id` like

```
Dim Deptid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(D_ddlDepartment.SelectedValue)
```